# Does Google Maps iOS have voice navigation

Tags: maps, google-maps, voice, navigation

I have been using Google Maps iOS (Australia) and i have never received voice navigation. Is this supported? And if so is it supported in Australia? And if so once again, where should I check to get this working. I am using an iPhone 6Plus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, voice navigation is available in Google Maps for Australia.

To enable it:

- Make sure you have the most-recent version of iOS.
- Make sure `Notifications` for the app are turned on.
- In the app, after you've started the navigation, tap on the 3 vertical dots on the bottom-right of the screen
- In the panel that slides up make sure `Mute` is `Off`.

Doing all this will allow you to hear the turn-by-turn navigation prompts.   [Here's](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6145865) a Google support site with additional information.